# page refresh not working while using https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, reactjs, https, apache2.2

we have built UI using react js framework and html +css + js code is deployed inside apache 2. When I browse website it works fine but if I refresh page then I get 404. Can someone tell me how can I fix it.

Comment: Do you use single-page-application router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this answer is relevant to you:

[Apache web server doesn't allow me to refresh on /about but on localhost its working fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32150653/apache-web-server-doesnt-allow-me-to-refresh-on-about-but-on-localhost-its-wor)

I know I also had problems related to HTML5 mode when first setting up react-router.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React-Router you are probably having this problem: [React-router urls don't work when refreshing or writting manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writting-manually).

You can also see [the React Router tutorial](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/11-productionish-server) for how to set up a production Express server.

Comment: It was working fine with http url, but while I hit the same url with https, I get 404.