# Refresh page on apache with React doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, reactjs, react-router-v4

I'm trying to use React to create a SPA, but I'm running into problem when trying to reload the page.

Before I continue, I must say I already read these questions [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writting-manually) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32150653/apache-web-server-doesnt-allow-me-to-refresh-on-about-but-on-localhost-its-wor). I manageg to made it work, but only for the first url.

For example, I have a blog page containing all the posts, accessed via this url `mysite.com/blog`. This one works fine, if I refresh the page, everything reloads again.

However, when I try to access a single post using a dynamic url, then the page doesn't work. For example, I have this router setup:

```
// Definiton
<Route path="/post/:url" component={Post} />

// Link
<NavLink to={"post/" + post.url}>...</NavLink>

// Url on the browser
mysite.com/post/this-is-my-first-post
```

In this case, it's not working. This is my `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

---

After looking more at the problem, I noticed it's trying to load the main files from a different location. For example, when I'm on the page `mysite.com/blog` it's loading the `.css` and `.js` files from `mysite.com`.

But when I'm the page `mysite.com/post/this-is-my-first-post` and I refresh the page, it's trying to load the `.css` and `.js` files from the directory `mysite.com/blog`.

I did what Stuffix told in the answe, to check the url definition and also the config at my apache, but everything is enabled and working, just like the answer says.

Comment: Are you using Webpack ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after looking at some other projects I have using Angular, I noticed one thing, and it was easier than I tought.

Just had to add the tag `base` on the `head` of my `index.html`.

```
<base href="/" />
```

Comment: I was using `.htaccess` to rewrite all subirectory paths (via `ResourceFallback`) back to my "root" folder's `index.html` and was running into this issue. Silly enough your solution worked for me too over all of my `.htaccess` attempts.

Answer (score 1):

This htaccess worked for me with react and angular

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

# -- REDIRECTION to https (optional):
# If you need this, uncomment the next two commands
# RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
# RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
# --

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `<Route />`, you're declaring the post route is `/post/this-is-my-first-post` which is correct.

But in your `<NavLink />`, you're pointing towards `/blog/post/this-is-my-first-post` since you've missed a slash.

```
<NavLink to={"post/" + post.url}>...</NavLink>
              | here
```

Thus leading to a 404.

---

If this doesn't help, your snippet looks fine so the problem might be on what does `post.url` returns.

Also, your .htaccess looks fine so I would say you might have missed something in your Apache config like `AllowOverride all`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22526144/2383691).

Comment: I updated my question. I tried to do what you said, but it didn't solved. Also, the main problem is not navigating to the post url, I can do it just fine. The problem is when I type the url on the address bar or try to refresh when i'm on that page.