# React Subdomain Goes to Main Site 404

Tags: .htaccess, reactjs, react-router, react-redux, single-page-application

URLs on my subdomain like react.mysite.com/page1 go to mysite.com/404.html, when refreshed, instead of the appropriate React component.

Can i have a seperate .htaccess for my subdomain? If so what would I write in it so it would look at react.mysite.com and let that handle the rest of the url?

I'm relatively new to React and SPA, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can have multiple .htaccess files.
And the rule is available in this question:

[Apache web server doesn't allow me to refresh on /about but on localhost its working fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32150653/apache-web-server-doesnt-allow-me-to-refresh-on-about-but-on-localhost-its-wor)