# Multipage React App Deployment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment

I have a multipage React App that I have used the create-react-app tool to make, however it's come to the point where I need to deploy it. The issue I am having is that the Router doesn't seem to work properly when I upload to cPanal, for example /Library will throw a 404, when locally it will just serve the /Library page.

Does anyone have any experience with deploying multipage apps with React to cPanal?

Comment: You will need to configure the server to serve your react app main file on any request. Unfortunately, I don't have the experience with doing it in cPanel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has actually been answered here.

cPanal has a .htaccess file but it's hidden. It just needs opening up and editing to include the code from the answer to the question below.

[Apache web server doesn't allow me to refresh on /about but on localhost its working fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32150653/apache-web-server-doesnt-allow-me-to-refresh-on-about-but-on-localhost-its-wor/32150846#32150846)

Answer (score 1):

**you need .htaccess file in your public directory.**

First make sure that .htaccess file is in your document root (the same place as index.html) or it'll only affect the sub-folder it's in (and any sub-folders within that - recursively).

> Simplest example of .htaccess file to achive what you want. Create .htaccess file in your public directory and put below code in that

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

what it does ? it simply loads the index.html on every request.
eg. if you hits  /Library in a browser it loads the index.html in which your react app is instantiate.

Comment: Works for any single-page WebApp (not specific to React). Tx!

Comment: I was able to get by with one line: `RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]`