# Page not found when hard refresh - Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm developing ReactJs Application.I'm getting page not found (404) error when i hard refresh the build page.but its work fine (page routing) with button click.

**index.js**

```
ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
            <div className="wrapper">
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
                    <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} />
                    <Route path="/faq" component={Faq} />
                    <Route path="/privacy" component={Privacy} />                    
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
</Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 3000,
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
}
```

[browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4PeQ.png)

i got this error,when i tried to run my build bundle.but it's work charmly when i run `npm start`.
(404 got when run build app)

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32150653/apache-web-server-doesnt-allow-me-to-refresh-on-about-but-on-localhost-its-wor and this - https://dzone.com/articles/how-use-htaccess-file

Answer (score 1):

If you running this on server, most likely the server configuration matches the url, and responds the 404 without react.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an exact path for / ,otherwise it will match with nothing, it means path="" then cannot find this address in routing so get the page(404).

```
 <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
```

also, you can try below way path="", it should works.

```
<Route path="" component={Home} />
```

Comment: i've tried both ways.but still show 404 when refresh

Comment: in render function try this 
  if (window.location.pathname==='"') {
    return <Redirect to="/" />;
  }
set "/" to Home component and try it

Answer (score 0):

```
    <Route component={400page} />
```

look if the user add router not found  it will be shown page not found an error
Now if the user isn’t at / or /profile,faq, privacy the 400pagecomponent will be rendered.

read this articles it will explain clear

Answer (score 0):

If hosted in Apache server then create ***.htaccess*** file
paste the below cotent

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

reference link

https://ui.dev/react-router-cannot-get-url-refresh